# Emacs Through Putty

Tags: windows, emacs, split, putty

So I opened emacs through putty by executing the command "emacs -nw FILENAME", where emacs opens up with the desired file. I split the screen in emacs in order to open different file by executing the command "C-x 2" in emacs to split the window horizontally so that I can view two windows at a time.

My question is, now that I can view both files next to each other through the split screen, how do I edit the other file? (I can't use the mouse to click on the other file (other split window) to edit it because I can only use key commands when using emacs through putty)

Comment: It is possible to use tramp mode over putty, allowing you to run emacs locally and edit remote files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use C-x o, `other-window`.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-Window.html.

Comment: Alright thanks so much! So when I split a screen three times horizontally, one split window is bigger than the others, so is there any way that I can make them all the same size evenly?

Comment: And is there also a way to access the files and go to the putty command prompt at the same time to see the other files that I can open?

Comment: OpMt: please ask new questions instead of comments for these.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try the Emacs tutorial which will explain those things.  Also, I believe it is possible to get mouse clicks to work under putty: try `M-x xterm-mouse-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

Another tip to use the other window as a terminal is to run:
    M-x term